# How was multiprogramming brought into computer languages

Tags: programming-languages, concurrency, history

I am going through the book operating system principles by Hansen . Hansen begins the third chapter on concurrent programming by discussing interleaving of the machine instructions of processes being run at the same time .

Then it begins with providing the language notation for multiprogramming  and writes the following program whose purpose is to copy  records from one sequence to another .

```
procedure copy (var f, g: sequence of T);
var s, t: T; 
     completed: boolean; 
begin 
    if not empty(f) 
    then 
        begin 
            completed:= false;
            get(s, f);
            repeat 
                 t:= s; 
                 cobegin 
                       put(t, g); 
                       if empty(f) 
                       then 
                            completed:= true 
                       else 
                            get(s, f); 
                 coend 
            until completed; 
        end
 end
```

(If possible please tell me the name of the language ,was it Algol60 ?Anyways let's call it X )

All fine till here , a keyword or statement was introduced into the language X , which would perform multiprogramming. But I would like to know how was the language changed so as to incorporate this new keyword or function for multiprogramming . What changes were done to language X,owing to which X which was capable of supporting one execution at a time could now support more than one at a time ?

P.S : Hansen described about a single -user operating system called "Solo ".There he somehow means Pascal supports development of concurrent programs. The answer to the question in this post can be approximated by an answer to "what were the differences between languages which supported concurrent programs and those who didn't "?

I could have written "what are the differences" in the auxiliary question but I wanted to know how languages started having constructs for concurrent programming ,that's why I wrote "What were the differences".

Comment: It's my impression that the first high level language to get system specific extensions for parallel operations was Fortran. For example the CDC 6600 (1960's) followed by other mainframes and/or super computers that supported "vector" operations. These early extensions were system specific and non-portable. Some of the early code was also done with assembly. Multi-processing for user programs is mostly handled via function calls related to synchronization and memory sharing.

Comment: @rcgldr : That's what I want to know , The process of adding Function calls related to synchronization and memory sharing to the language . Could you elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: For the function calls, no language changes are needed. For example, in the case of windows, the functions are CreateThread(), CreateProcess(), CreateSemaphore(), WaitForSingleObject(), WaitForMultipleObjects(), CreateFileMapping (using invalid file handle) for shared memory between processes, and other functions. The libraries would need to support multi-threading, but the actual language needs no changes.

Comment: @rcgldr : were these functions included in the language ?I mean as in keywords , were these functions keywords in the languages of those time ? How were the libraries created ?

Comment: @rcgldr : But Posix didn't exist back then . What are these libraries of visual studio written in ?

Comment: `back then` - What time frame are you referring to. Back in the 1960's and the days of mainframes or perhaps Windows NT (1990's) or later for PCs? By Posix, I was also considering Unix as part of the Posix family but I don't know if classic Unix is considered as part of the Posix family. I assume the VIsual Studio libraries are written in C (based on the actual names used by the linker). There may be some tiny bit of assembler, but I don't know.

Comment: @itpdusra: The only language change was an acknowledgement that there might be multiple threads running (which has certain consequences); how threads could be started or finished was and often still is outside the computer language. Some C compilers needed changing, because with multiple threads possible, the compiler must not introduce race conditions in compiled code that are not present in the source code. And for bit fields, rules were added to C saying whether different threads modifying nearby but different bitfields is a race condition or not.

Comment: @gnasher729 :In that case , is it impossible for programmers create and end threads at their own will ?

Comment: I don't think history of programming languages is ontopic here. Shouldn't this be on [SO] or [softwareengineering.SE]?

Comment: @itpdusra: A C implementation consists of a compiler and an implementation of the standard library. Until a short time ago, creating threads was neither part of the language and of the standard library. However, there have been different libraries, for example the Posix pthreads library, or the Windows specific functions mentioned earlier, that could handle threads. You couldn't create a threading library (like pthreads) portably in pure C. But of course you could _use_ that library to create threads for a long time.

Comment: @gnasher729 : So , if not in C in what languages I can create threading library ? I mean there must have been something new in any language which started supporting programs to run parallel to each other  . Must not there be a translation into an assembly language program to run two programs in parallel ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're **really** interested in all that's needed, your best choice would be to look at the standardisation process of C++11 by the ISO Working Group on C++ (WG21). All the relevant papers are available online.

Keywords are *not* important at all. In fact, C++ defined just one new keyword (`thread_local`) and that's mostly for convenience.

What *is* important is the *memory model*. Programs work by altering state, which logically exists in memory. With multi-programming, there are concurrent changes to the state of a program. This requires a reasonably precise definition of said state. To make things more complex, you want a definition of state that is compatible not just with the abstract language definition, but which is also implementable on real hardware. That gets you into problems like registers and  caches (state outside ordinary memory), the exact details of which vary significantly between real hardware architectures.

A key insight here is the *sequenced* concept. Two C++ operations can be *sequenced*, which means they cannot operate at the same time. This means they are allowed to use the same data in memory without risk. A special kind of sequencing is *sequenced before*, which means one operations happens before the other. This means a write *sequenced before* a read guarantees that the read sees the value of the write.

With C++11, there are library calls defined which can guarantee such sequencing across different threads of execution.

The comments of @rcgldr suggest that function calls like `WaitForSingleObject` alone are sufficient, but this isn't actually the case. You need an associated memory model. That's why you have Win32 macro's like `InterlockedIncrement` - these macro's provide the mapping between the language memory model and the hardware memory model. There's no `Read(DWORD*)` macro, though - the language memory model is that aligned `DWORD` reads are atomic, and it's implicitly assumed that the compiler can efficiently map every read to atomic hardware instructions.

Comment: My gratefulness for your reply .By keywords I meant words pertaining to starting simultaneously running programs . Do parallelly or simultaneously programs actually fall under sequenced programs ?I am a bit confused as cooperating programs are supposed to operate together and sequential ones don't.

Comment: https://isocpp.org/forums...were you referring to this link . Could you tell me where in this link should I look for ?

Comment: :What exactly the library calls written in  ?